# Changing how DataGrid Bind to a list in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a collection bind to a grid view 
I understand that the default for a GridView is to show the column header as the property name and the records for the values of these property

but assuming I have this collection

```
{
  Object1 { Name : First One , Value : 11}
  Object2 { Name : Second One, Value : 22}
}
```

the default in grid view is to show

```html
<table >
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Value</th> 

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>First Name </td>
    <td>11</td> 
    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Second Name </td>
    <td>22</td> 
 
  </tr>
</table>
```

but I want it to be like this

First one ------------ Second One

11   ---------------------- 22

LIne
second line

how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to:
https://www.grapecity.com/en/blogs/4-steps-to-creating-an-inverted-datagrid

This will transpose your gridview to show rows as columns and columns as rows.

Comment: thank you... but this is not what I am looking for ...
I am looking to set the header as a value of the property not the property itself!.

Comment: @GhostCat Others have marked the question for editing too, plus you've edited the question. I don't see your point here.

Comment: A) if the majority of voters would make the correct decision, I wouldnt have contacted you (and the other two guys). B) I edited the question, simply because I spent minutes looking at it, and in the end, I am collecting edits on that queue ... C) there is a common misconception regarding the "edit" action. It doesnt mean what you think it means .... you vote EDIT when **anybody** (not the OP!) can **fix** the question and make it answerable. This question needs to be improved by the OP. Other editors cant fix it. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: In this specific case, the question is a zero effort "do my homework" dump. And as such, the reasonable choice is to downvote it, and close vote as "too broad" for example.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the only way is to change the data form 
so we take value property form both objects to and create on ValueObject
and we use the name property to manually name the headers.